# How to place marker on floorplan image

Tags: html, google-maps, openstreetmap

Is there any API which help us to use our floorplan image with zooming functionality . And it should also helps to place location marker on top of the floorplan image based on pixel values.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gdal2Tiles for Leaflet (https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet): you need to execute the python script and follow the readme to create the html page with leaflet. With the rastercoords.js plugin you can place markers on the image.